# Convert value of a variable using AtrributeConverter based on an enum value

Tags: java, spring, jpa, type-conversion

I have recently learned about AttributeConverter< x,y >. I have values of different datatypes which shall be passed as object into the convertToDatabaseColumn function and shall return a string. However, while converting it back to object in convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData), I have to convert the value into different datatypes according to an enum variable in the entity and finally return it as an object. For further processing, there will be a check if the object value is an instance of the specific datatype. I am unable to find a way to pass any other value to the converter apart from the value that needs to be converted. Is there any way that I can implement it??

```
public class entityClass{
  EnumType enumValue;

  @Lob
  @Converter(myconverter.class)
  Object valueToConvert;

 //constructor, getters and setters
 }
```

` While converting it back from database, it does the conversion to different datatypes based on enumType value. Can I somehow pass this enumValue to my converter class for the comparison?

Comment: So you're saying the result type of the conversion should be dependent on the `enumValue` attribute of the entity? That sounds dodgy to say the least.

Comment: yes, the result type shall first be converted into Long, String or any other wrapper class and then finally returned as an object.

Comment: well, I have a table in database that holds enumvalues as variables and its data. The data is of different datatypes being saved as string in the table.

Answer (score 0):

My idea to solve this problem can be - wrap your `enumValue` and `valueToConvert` in a wrapper class.
Then write a converter for this wrapper class. The converter can convert the wrapper class to a delimited string, json or whatever you want. When reading from the database, parse this string and build the wrapper object.
However I agree with daniu's comment that it's not a good design.

Answer (score 0):

In the converter class you can have all enum classes with their values. So u can check and convert to proper data type

```
for (EnumType enum : EnumType.values()) {
    // do what you want
}
```